# Where is Nyjora?

Tags: zones-of-thought, a-fire-upon-the-deep

In [*A Fire Upon the Deep*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1952), the humans reference the planet or country called "*Nyjora*" as being their ancestral home.

Is this place on Earth?  I would look it up but I don't have my copy here.  I do remember a reference to Earth when they mention the story behind *Aniara* as being a ghost ship from Earth.

Answer (score 22):

Humans in the Beyond know that their race originally came from a place they call Old Earth, but they know little more; it was a very long time ago ([at least 30,000 years](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32417/does-the-book-a-fire-upon-the-deep-ever-give-an-exact-date), possibly much more) and it's in the Slow Zone and thus inaccessible.

Nyjora was the first world settled by humans who (inadvertedly) escaped the Slow Zone. It went through a period of feudalist matriarchy (The Age of Princesses occasionally mentioned in the books) and all humans in the Beyond are ultimately descended from there.

Comment: I have the impression that Nyjora itself is just below the zone boundary.  Support for this: it's never mentioned in present tense in *AFutD*.

Answer (score 6):

"Nyjora" comes from the words for "New Earth" in the Nordic languages (e.g. Norwegian).

Comment: The question is where is Nyjora. Or what does it mean. Whilst this does answer the former it needs making a bit more clearer as it currently reads like it’s just answering the latter.